# React context is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

Not sure why this is happening, I have checked to make sure that the states value is not undefined which it isnt and i cant see where im going wrong.

My authContext.js file

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthorized: false,
}

export const authContext = React.createContext() 

export default function AuthContextComp(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)

  return (
    <authContext.Provider authState={state}>
      {props.children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  )
}

function reducer(state, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'signIn':
      return true;
      break;
  
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My app file

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, appProps }) {

  return (
    <GlobalContextWrapper pageData={pageProps}>
      <AuthContextWrapper>
        <div style={{textAlign:'center',paddingTop: 200}}>
          <h2>Signed in</h2>
          <button>Log in or log out</button>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Test/>
        </div>
      </AuthContextWrapper>
    </GlobalContextWrapper>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

The component im trying to use the context in

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import {authContext} from '../global/authContext/AuthContext'

export default function Test() {
  const t = useContext(authContext)
  return (
    <div>
       This is the test component
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can you see anything wrong here? Im using next.js and i cant figure out why not

Comment: `authContext.Provider` does this need to be captialised? `AuthContext.Provider`

Comment: @evolutionxbox no it does not.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is it a convention? [React docs say](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) _"Note: Always start component names with a capital letter."_

Comment: @evolutionxbox the component name is `Provider`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that the context has a property called 'provider' which is a component which is why its capitalised

Comment: I don't think `authState` is a valid prop. Try `value` instead?

Comment: Correct @evolutionbox - I thought you could name it anything but apparently not!

Answer (score 3):

Issue was that when passing state into the provide the name should be value. Not sure why this would be the case

```
    <authContext.Provider  value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </authContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Because [that's what the documentation says to do](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

Comment: To elaborate slightly on @PatrickRoberts terse response, the `Provider` component is internally defined by React when you create the context.  In that definition, it has a `value` prop that takes the type the `Context` holds.  It's "just how it works" :)